# Como invocar el valor de un metodo desde otro metodo?

Tags: python

Un cordial saludo a toda la comunidad, cual es la manera mas correcto de hacer esto? Agradecido!

Como invocar el valor de un metodo, desde otro metodo, dentro de la misma clase. Cuales son las maneras mas correctas de hacerlo?

Aqui plantie un ejemplo basico para visualizar el contexto

```
class Adicion:
    def suma (self):
        x = 2+2
    def resta (self, x):
        return x - 2
    def operacion(self):
        self.suma()
        return self.resta(x)

prueba = Adicion()
prueba.operacion()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO Español, no consigo entender tu pregunta, por favor podrías editarla para así ayudarte mejor?

Comment: Por favor, explica cual parametro, desde cual función a cual otra.

Comment: Pienso que esta pregunta está basada en opiniones, ya que hay muchas maneras de hacerlo. Para una persona la manera *correcta* será una y para otra persona otra. Por favor lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), trata plantea una pregunta dudas puntuales o problemas en específico. Saludos

Comment: Puedes retornar valores en un método e invocarlos en otro método de la misma clase: `foo = self.metodo()`. También puedes definirlos como como atributos de la clase en un método, así tendría scope global dentro la clase: `self.foo = 3 + 3`.

Comment: Agradecido por la pronta respuesta, me disculpo por no haber formulado la pregunta correctamente, soy nuevo. La pregunta era: Como invocar el valor de un metodo, desde otro metodo, dentro de la misma clase. Cuales eran las maneras mas correctas de hacerlo.

Comment: No hay problema, También es bueno que aceptes la respuesta que mejor te ha ayudado (con el "tick" que hay al lado de cada respuesta) por dos motivos: primero ayuda a otro usuario que encuentre tu pregunta a tener la certeza de que la respuesta es correcta y segundo que si no lo haces dentro de unos meses el bot volverá a subir tu pregunta al principio pensando que ninguna respuesta es valida para que alguien más lo intente o participe. Un saludo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero de todo deberías entender que las variables tienen una "visibilidad" que en ingles llaman `scope` y es básicamente que una variable normalmente puede ser accedida "hacia adentro"

Por ejemplo:

```
a = 1
b = 2
def suma(c,d);
    return c + d

def identidad(e):
    print(a)
    print(e)

class Objeto:
    f = 2
    def identidadObjeto(g):
        print(f)
        print(g)
    def sumaObjeto(h,j):
        print(h+j)
        print(g)
```

Se puede acceder a las variables "a y b" desde cualquier parte de ese script, las variables "c y d" solo son accesibles desde dentro de `suma()` y si intentas accedes desde fuera te salta error porque "no las puedes ver desde fuera".

Sin embargo si que puedes acceder a la variable "a" desde dentro de `identidad()`.

Lo mismo ocurre con la clase `Objeto`, podrías instanciar la clase y acceder a la variable "f" (sólo despues de instanciar), pero no podrías acceder a las variables "g,h y j" porque están dentro de sus funciones y no puedes "verlas" desde fuera, por lo que la función `sumaObjeto()` dentro de `Objeto` te dará fallo porque la variable "g" está únicamente dentro de la función `identidadObjeto()`. Ambas podrían acceder a las variables "a,b y f".

Y segundo, antes de crear clases piensa bien si la necesitas, puesto que muchas veces una simple función es más simple y fácil de entender que una clase. Pedagogicamente está bien aprender a usarlas, pero luego eso no significa que tengas que usarlas porque sepas sino solo cuando tiene sentido usarlas. Una clase que te haga una suma o una resta tiene valor académico pero no tiene ninguna utilidad puesto que ya puedes hacer esas sumas con los operadores matemáticos que tiene Python.

Un saludo,

Comment: Jose, gracias por tomar un espacio de tu valioso tiempo para ayudarme.

Comment: Jose, yo te puedo mandar por alguna otra via lo que yo estoy tratando de hacer? es un algoritmo basico estructurado y un amigo que me esta guiando me dijo que convirtiera ahora ese codigo estructurado a POO.

Comment: Le invito a que cualquier duda que tenga la haga pública aquí en StackOverflow (siguiendo las normas de la comunidad) para que todo el mundo pueda ayudarle y aprender.

Comment: Te segui tu recomendacion de hacer la duda publica y me mandaron a hacer una pregunta en concreto, al final no pude solucionar...

Answer (score 2):

Las funciones pueden tener atributos, que puede ser usados y modificados por otras funciones.

Hagamos un ejemplo sencillo: tenemos una función que retorna el cuadrado del valor recibido. Queremos conservar el último argumento recibido. Para eso usaremos la forma `nombre_funcion.nombre_atributo = valor` para guardar el último argumento en el atributo `last`.

```
def fcn_cuadrado(x):
    fcn_cuadrado.last = x
    return x ** 2
```

Otra función puede acceder a ese valor. Por ejemplo, está función que calcula el cubo del valor calculado por `fcn_cuadrado`:

```
def fcn_cubo():
    return fcn_cuadrado.last ** 3
```

Otras funciones no solo pueden leer el atributo; también pueden modificarlo directamente.

Ahora, si ejecutamos estas lineas:

```
print(fcn_cuadrado(3))
print(fcn_cubo())
```

obtendremos:

```
9
27
```

**Aplicaciones prácticas**

En general es aplicable en general cuando la función necesita mantener estado entre llamada y llamada.

Una aplicación práctica de esta posibilidad es la técnica llamada *memorización*. La idea es que si tienes una función costosa que llamas repetidas veces con los mismos argumentos, te conviene acordarte del o los valores previamente calculados. Si te vuelven a llamar con el mismo argumento, devuelves el valor almacenado, sin necesidad de repetir el calculo.

Apliquemos la técnica a la función `fcn_cuadrado`:

```
def fcn_cuadrado(x):
    if not hasattr(fcn_cuadrado, "last") or fcn_cuadrado.last != x:
        print("nuevo valor", x)
        fcn_cuadrado.last = x
        fcn_cuadrado.value = x ** 2
    return fcn_cuadrado.value
```

Vamos a usar el atributo `last` para guardar el último argumento y el atributo `value` para guardar el valor calculado.

Primero hay que preguntar si el atributo existe (está creado), de lo contrario se genera una excepción. Para eso se ocupa la función `hasattr(nombre_funcion, nombre_atributo)`.

Si el `last` no existe o es distinto al argumento recibido, se realiza el calculo y se almacenan los valores.

Finalmente, se retorna el valor calculado desde el valor almacenado.

**Prueba**

```
print(fcn_cuadrado(3))
print(fcn_cuadrado(3))
print(fcn_cuadrado(3))
print(fcn_cuadrado(4))
```

produce

```
nuevo valor 3
9
9
9
nuevo valor 4
16
```

Como se demuestra, solo la primera vez se realiza el cálculo.

**Observaciones**

La memorización puede ser tan refinada como se quiera. Por ejemplo, en lugar de almacenar sólo el último cálculo, se puede usar un diccionario para almacenar todos los cálculos previos (sin repeticiones).

Comment: Candid, gracias por tomar un espacio de tu valioso tiempo para ayudarme, estuve leyendo todo lo que me estabas enseñando, gracias! 
Quise aplicar el primer ejemplo que me pusiste dentro de una clase y me da error, que era lo que en principio buscaba, de todas maneras, entendi el contexto de lo que quisiste explicarme.

Answer (score -1):

bienvenido, si vas a usar variables que se utilizan en varios metodos te recomiendo mas facil declarar las variables globales o dentro de la misma clase o instancia, luego desde el metodo suma llamas a  la variable x, eso te permite no tener que llamar a x cada rato si no el metodo suma, un error del codigo te faltaba declarar la x en el metodo operacion o un metodo como suma o resta que contenga x, esto impirimira el resultado no se si es lo que buscas

```
    x = 2

class Adicion:
    #Declarar variables
    def suma (self,x):
        #global x tambien funciona
        x = 2+2
    def resta (self, suma):
        self.suma(x)
        return x - 2
    def operacion(self,x):#funciona si llamas a suma o resta
        self.resta(x)
        return self.resta(x)


prueba = Adicion()
prueba.operacion(x)
print(prueba.operacion(x))
```

Comment: Las variables globales son problemáticas. Polucionan el código con variables que a nadie más importan, y que pueden ser confundidas con otras variables de nombre similares. Hay opciones mejores, como usar variables de instancia o de clase.