# Error de asignación de variable local

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, condiciones

**Hola muchachos, ¿alguien podría ayudarme? por favor. El error que me arroja es por una asignación incorrecta en mis variables dentro de mi función, pero aún estoy algo nueva en esto de la programación y no puedo encontrar mi error ni una solución a la misma. Les gradeceré mucho :) **

Para mi función de cálculo de carga y proporción de aminoácidos con carga en una proteína:

```
def carga_y_prop(AAseq):
    
    protseq = AAseq.upper() 
    carga = -0.002
    cp_o = 0
    AACarga = {"C":-.045,"D":-.999,"E":-.998,"H":.091,"K":1,"R":1,"Y":-.001}
    
    for aa in protseq:
        carga+= AACarga.get(aa,0)
    if aa in AACarga:
        cp_o += 1
        prop = 100*cp_o/len(AAseq)


    return (carga, prop)
```

Al intoducir lo siguiente:

```
>>> carga_y_prop("QTALLVVLVLLAVALQATEAGPYGA")
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in carga_y_prop
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prop' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Prueba colocando el return dentro del "if" y me dices

Comment: ¿El if no debería de estar dentro del for? Así lo puse y me imprimió _(-1.001, 8.0)_

Comment: Yo diria que sí @Firefly pero no tengo ni idea de cosas de proteinas, quién sabe! Pero aun así sigue teniendo un problema porque si la condición del if no se cumple nunca, intenta hacer un return con una variable inexistente.

Comment: Por eso debe inicializarla antes del for, como se lo explican en las respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo añadir a la solución de Candid Moe lo siguiente:

Python es un lenguaje interpretado en tiempo de ejecución: significa que el código no se compila por completo sino cuando lo ejecutas, por lo que no es capaz "por si mismo" de encontrar esas trampas de principiante en la que has caído.

El error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prop' referenced before assignment

significa que has utilizado la variable `prop` "ANTES" de decirle qué valor tiene. Como dice Candid Moe, creas una variable dentro de un condicional (if/else) y eso es pecado; si tu código en ese momento (o en cualquier otro momento) no cumple la condición que le pones...

```
if aa in AACarga: # Si no existe "aa" dentro de AACarga cp_o no se incrementa y prop no existe
        cp_o += 1
        prop = 100*cp_o/len(AAseq)
```

...`prop` nunca existirá en el curso actual del programa, y a efectos de recolección de basura tampoco existió nunca porque desaparece cuando la función `carga_y_prop(AAseq)` termina. Sin embargo `cp_o` si que sigue existiendo durante la función porque está declarado antes al inicio de esta.

Debes entender que las variables que uses "existen" dentro de su "nido de ejecución" por llamarlo de alguna forma. Lo más cómodo es inicializar las variables que sabes que vas a utilizar al principio de la función/método como has hecho con `protseq`, `carga` y `cp_o`

(Relacionado: [Como invocar el valor de un metodo desde otro metodo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/382545/44710) )

Answer (score 1):

La variable `prop` solo es inicializada cuando se cumple `if aa in AACarga:`

Si no es el caso, `prop` no tiene ningún valor asignado, por lo que falla al intentar retornarlo en

```
return (carga, prop)
```

**Solución**

Inicializar prop en algún valor por default apropiado al entrar a la función (por ejemplo).